# Removing extra spaces after i enter a string

Tags: string, assembly, mips

Hi i was wondering if there was a simple way to remove the spaces i allocated for a string to be entered, or perhaps a way to not compare the empty space after the word. This program is a palindrome detector. Any suggestions would be great.

Ex. output:

racecar, not a palindrome because it has a few empty spaces.

aaaaaaaaaa is a palindrome because it has no empty spaces...

again just need a hotfix to remove the spaces after the word is inputted, or a way to ignore the spaces after the word. Thank You.

```
.data

intro : .asciiz "Lets See If Your Word is a Palinfrome!\n"

question: .asciiz "Please Enter up to a 10 Character word: "

Y_P: .asciiz "Yes it is!"

N_P: .asciiz "No Its Not!"

str1: .space 10


.text

.globl main
main:


li $v0, 4 
la $a0, intro
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, question
syscall

li $v0, 8
la $a0,str1
addi $a1,$zero,10


syscall

move $t0, $a0

palindrome:
 addi $t0, $0, 0 # j = 0
length: add $t2, $a0, $t0 # $t2 = &array[j]
 lb $t2, 0($t2) # $t2 = array[j]
 beq $t2, $0, done # end of string?
 addi $t0, $t0, 1 # j = j+1
 j length
done: addi $t0, $t0, -1 # j = j-1
 addi $t1, $0, 0 # i = 0
loop: slt $t2, $t1, $t0 # $t2 = 1 if i < j
 beq $t2, $0, yes # if !(i < j) return
 add $t2, $a0, $t1 # $t2 = &array[i]
 lb $t2, 0($t2) # $t2 = array[i]
 add $t3, $a0, $t0 # $t3 = &array[j]
 lb $t3, 0($t3) # $t3 = array[j]
 bne $t2, $t3, no # is palindrome?
 addi $t0, $t0, -1 # j = j-1
 addi $t1, $t1, 1 # i = i+1
 j loop
yes: # yes a palindrome
 addi $v0, $0, 1

 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Y_P
 syscall 

 li $v0, 10
 syscall
 j yes
 jr $ra
no: # not a palindrome
 addi $v0, $0, 0

 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, N_P
 syscall 


 li $v0, 10
 syscall
 j no
 jr $ra
```

Comment: By _"spaces"_, do you mean the space character (ASCII 32), or something else? It seems to me like you already have a loop that calculates the string length by scanning for a `NUL` character (ASCII 0). So you could modify that loop to exit for any character that you don't consider to be part of the word.

Comment: im trying to set the loop to break when it detects a 
    (space: .asciiz " ")

i do this by loading the address of that string to $t9, then replace that with the zero in the get length loop. Problem is that its not working. any ideas?

Comment: basically, from what i can tell, i need to know what the extra space after input is equal to. So if i can enter 10 characters, i enter in "pop" what the loop is seeing is "p-o-p-_-_-_-_-_-_-\0, so what do i use, (instead of zero) to check for a blank space in the input " "